# How to add products to cart with woocommerce rest api and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce

i am currently working on the Frontend in React "local"
and Backend is wordpress/woocommerce, i am able to GET the products but i can't seem to POST.
this is the response i am getting.

{"code":"woocommerce_rest_missing_nonce","message":"Missing the Nonce header. This endpoint requires a valid nonce.","data":{"status":401}}

i have read a few different articles about the same problem but i still can't seem to get it to work.
can anyone help me?

````
import { Link, useParams, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useQuery, useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import fetchProduct from "../fetchProduct";

export default function ProductDetail() {
    const { id } = useParams()
    const results = useQuery(["products", id], fetchProduct)
    const product = results?.data;
    const location = useLocation();
    const search = location.state?.search || "";

    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1); 

  const addToCartMutation = useMutation(async () => {
    const authHeaders = new Headers();
    const credentials = btoa('ck_xxxx:cs_xxxx');
    authHeaders.append('Authorization', `Basic ${credentials}`);
    
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`https://alive-industry.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart/items`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          ...authHeaders,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          product_id: id,
          quantity: quantity,
        }),
      });
  
      // Rest of the code...
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  });
  
    if (results.isLoading) {
        return <h3>Loading Product...</h3>;
    }

    if (results.isError) {
        return <h3>Error: {results.error.message}</h3>;
    }

    return (
        <>
        <div className="product-detail">
            <div className="product-spec-conatiner">
                <Link to={`..${search}`} relative="path">
                    &larr;
                    <span> Back to all Products</span>
                </Link>
                <h3 className="product-name">{product.name}</h3>
                <span>$ {product.price}</span>
                <p className="product-description" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product.description }} />
                
                {product.type !== "simple" ? 
                <>
                <h3>Sizes:</h3>
                <select>
                  {product?.attributes[0]?.options.map(option => 
                  <option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>)}
                </select>
                </> : ""}
                <br />
                <input
                    type="number"
                    min="1"
                    value={quantity}
                    onChange={(e) => setQuantity(parseInt(e.target.value))}
                />
                <button onClick={() => addToCartMutation.mutate()}>Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
            <div className="product-img-container">
                <img src={product.images[0].src} alt={product.name} />
            </div>
            <div className="product-thumbs-container">
                {product.images.map((image, id) => (
                    <img src={image.src} key={id}/>
                ))}
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </>
    )
} ```
````

Comment: For your testing you can disable it using add_filter( 'woocommerce_store_api_disable_nonce_check', '__return_true' ); . As for production you need to pass nonce that the store wants wp_create_nonce('wc_store_api').  Check the last comment here - https://github.com/RayOkaah/woocommerce/issues/7

Comment: @Snuffy Thank you for your answer, i've followed the example you've sent but now i am getting a 403 forbidden error, "nonce is invalid"
i don't know why and have been trying to solve this but with no success.
https://github.com/bukke101/alive-industry-test/tree/master

Comment: If i tried Disabling it gave no errors but no item are added to cart either..

Comment: did you pass it properly ? headers: { 'X-WP-Nonce', wp_create_nonce('wc_store_api'), } ?

Comment: yes but then i seem to be getting a reference error, i can't seem to figure this one out

Comment: Maybe its preventing  cross-site request  ? Without debuging could be just a guess.

Comment: I have a enable cors plugin installed on wordpress..

Comment: you can see example on my git /src/pages
/ProductDetail.jsx
maybe i did something wrong there?